# Why is vim not being opened in its own screen?

Tags: fedora, vim, xterm

When I type `vim` in `xterm` the program is not opened in its own screen, but in the very same I am writing commands in. Let me explain: for example, lets say I type in the terminal `ls -l /usr/bin` and get a big list of programs. After that I type `vim` and the program is opened, but if I scroll up I can still see the list of programs in `/usr/bin`. As far as I remember, when I opened `vim` it would start in a clean screen with nothing behind it, so if I wanted to go back to the terminal I had to quit.

[image: Here is a screenshot of what is happening]

Why is `vim` behaving like this and how can I change it?

Comment: What is your `$TERM`? Maybe whatever it is set to does not have support for `t_ti` and `t_ks`?

Comment: It is `xterm-256color`. I think I set it manually adding the line `XTerm.termName: xterm-256color` to my `.Xresources`.

Comment: And do you see the same effect if you set `TERM=xterm`?

Answer (score 2):

The question is about the behavior of the application versus the *alternate screen* feature of xterm.

vim is a termcap application.  It uses the terminal database (possibly provided by ncurses), but does all of its own screen management (like any other termcap application).

By convention, termcap and curses applications send escape sequences at initialization and when returning from full-screen mode.  Those escape sequences come from *terminal capabilities* (the origin of the name "termcap").

The capabilities for starting and ending full-screen cursor-addressing mode are named `smcup` and `rmcup` respectively (in terminfo, while `ti` and `te` for termcap).  By convention, those *may* have the escape sequences for switching to/from the alternate screen.  While the alternate screen is active, xterm disallows scrolling.

However, *convention* does not ensure that all terminal descriptions for `xterm` are the same.  Some packagers modify the description, because

- about half of the users like the feature, half dislike it (each half insists it is the majority), and
- not all terminals are as configurable as xterm.

  In xterm, you can enable/disable the switching to/from the alternate screen.  A *minority* of other terminals which set `TERM=xterm` allow you to do this.  That lack of configurability aggravates the half of the users who dislike the feature.

Depending on which packager has been modifying things, you may find that `TERM=xterm` does one thing with the alternate screen, while `TERM=xterm-256color` does the other.  If you use `infocmp` to look, an unmodified description would have these capabilities set to tell the application how to use the alternate screen:

```
rmcup=\E[?1049l, smcup=\E[?1049h,
```

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (xterm FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Apparently I completely mis-read the question, and the answer below is wrong. However, some comments on this answer clarify the question, so I'm leaving it.

`vim` is a "terminal program".  That is, it knows nothing of X windows or any other GUI interface. If you run `vim` by typing `vim` in an xterm, it will happily run there. Xterm has character-cell-addressable display, so `vim` will work with that.

You could get `vim` to run in its own xterm: `xterm -e vim whatever.file.name &`.

Or you could run a variant of `vim` that understands the X window system: `gvim`. When I type `gvim text.file.name` in an xterm and run it, I get a separate window containing a GUI version of `vim`.

Comment: As far as I can tell the question is about failing to run in the alternate screen, rather than anything about X windows.

Comment: @ChrisDown That's right, I want it to run in the terminal as usual. What is puzzling me is that it wasn't behaving as like this yesterday. Today, the only thing I have done is to navigate the file system trying to open some `.txt` files here and there, but nothing else. I haven't touched anything.

Answer (score 0):

Once I understood the question, I found out a possible answer, because I had noticed that change in behavior some time ago.

I believe this comes from a difference in the "terminfo" capabilities between xterm and xterm-256color.  Vim uses ncurses to do the in-window character manipulation, and "terminfo" is part of that.  Given that, you could look at dates (ctime, probably) of the terminfo capability files given below. That would explain why you did nothing, but still saw a change - terminfo files got changed.

I found terminfo files for xterm and xterm-256color in `/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm` and `/usr/share/terminfo/xterm-256color`, respectively. Those are binary files, but you can de-compile them with: `infocmp -L /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm > ~/xterm.ti`.  You can re-compile the `xterm.ti` text file with the `tic` command.  I believe that what you are talking about is related to "enter_ca_mode" and "exit_ca_mode" capabilities.  To test this, I made an alternate xterm terminfo entry for myself:

```
mkdir ~/.TERMINFO
infocmp -L /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm > ~/xterm.ti
// edit termifo.ti to remove enter_ca_mode" and "exit_ca_mode"
tic ~/xterm.ti
```

That leaves a file `~/.TERMINFO/x/xterm` in my $HOME directory. The environment variable TERM had a value of "xterm" in that xterm-window. Firing up `vim` again caused `vim` to behave roughly as you describe the new, undesireable behavior.  You'll probably have to delete `~/.TERMINFO` and contents to get rid of that modified xterm capabilities file's effects.

My thought would be to decompile xterm and xterm-256color terminfo entries using `infocmp -L` and see if they have different "enter_ca_mode" and "exit_ca_mode" values, or if xterm is missing it, and xterm-256color has it, or something. Then proceed from there. For what it's worth, on my up-to-date Arch linux laptop, xterm and xterm-256color had almost identical termcap capabilities.